# How to save Japanese filename in phpexcel?

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, phpexcel, filenames, cjk

I want to save a file with a Japanese name (Ex: ベトナム実習生候補者名簿.xls) by PHPExcel.

I tried the following code:

```
$fileName = iconv("utf-8", "CP932", "ベトナム実習生候補者名簿");
$newFile = $fileName.'xls';

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save($newFile);
```

and the result is: `ƒxƒgƒiƒ€ŽÀK¶Œó•âŽÒ–¼•ë.xls`

How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

That code works on my Windows (Windows 10 Home, Japanese version) without problem. I see the Japanese filename on Explorer.

Possible reasons I guess:

1. You did not save the php file as UTF-8 but something else.
2. Your terminal (if not default Windows Command Prompt) is not a CP932 mode. (You display CP932 filename with UTF-8 or others)

Comment: Thanks for your help